# Are electric hair straighteners allowed on flights?

Tags: air-travel, air-canada

My friend is travelling on Air Canada tomorrow from Toronto to Alberta. She is also travelling on Air Canada from Toronto to Los Angeles (California) next month. She was wondering if electric hair straighteners are allowed on flights. I think yes, but I would like some confirmation. Does the policy on what can be taken on flights change from one airline company to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is and is not allowed in carry-on baggage is generally not controlled by the airline itself, but instead by airport security.

As these flights depart from Canada, the rules are set by the Canadian Air Transport Security Authority, CATSA.

CATSA have a ["What can I bring?"](https://www.catsa-acsta.gc.ca/en) website where you can search for what items are allowed in carry-on and/or checked baggage.

Specifically for Hair Straighteners (aka Flat Irons), the answer is that [Yes, they are allowed](https://www.catsa-acsta.gc.ca/en/item/electric-hair-blow-dryers-curling-or-flat-irons).